# Randomly select file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, random

I'd like to use the 'include' keyword in php to randomly select a file from a folder and output the contents. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you know the folder where the files are and that the files are PHP files:

```
$phpFiles = glob('/path/to/files/*.php');

if (empty($phpFiles) === false)
{
    $randomFile = $phpFiles[array_rand($phpFiles)];
    include($randomFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) would read filenames into array.
and then you can shuffle this array and pick a random item.

Answer (score 1):

use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get an array of files. shuffle the array. [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) the first file off of the array. Include it.